# Replace a matching string from the end of line using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file content like,

```
/var/lib/mlocate
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mlocate.prerm
```

In the above file content I want to replace the last slash(/) on every line with space using sed like below

```
/var/lib mlocate
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.prerm
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's|\(.*\)/|\1 |' file
```

- `sed`'s regexes are *greedy* by default, so `.*/` matches everything up to the *last* `/` instance.
- `sed` uses BREs (*basic* regular expressions) by default, in which, perhaps surprisingly, `(` and `)` must be `\`-escaped in order to enclose a capture group (capture the enclosed sub-expression separately).

  - GNU (Linux) Sed and BSD/macOS Sed support nonstandard option `-E` to enable EREs (extended regular expressions), in which case you don't need the escaping of parentheses:
    `sed -E 's|(.*)/|\1 |' file    # or -r with GNU Sed / non-macOS BSD Sed`
- Note how regex delimiter `|` was chosen instead of the customary `/`; using `|` allows *unescaped* use of `/` as a *literal* to match.
- In the replacement part, `\1` refers to what the 1st (and only) capture group (`\(...\)`) matched, which is everything up to, but not including, the last `/`. By following `\1` with a literal space  you get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` version: NO reason to do the task with this. But it works :)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {$(NF-1)=$(NF-1) " " $NF; NF--} 1' inputfle
/var/lib mlocate
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info mlocate.prerm
```